# Remove duplicates in a row pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates, series

I have a df

```
Name  Symbol              Dummy
A     (BO),(BO),(AD),(TR)   2
B     (TV),(TV),(TV)        2
C     (HY)                  2
D     (UI)                  2
```

I need df as

```
Name  Symbol              Dummy
A     (BO),(AD),(TR)        2
B     (TV)                  2
C     (HY)                  2
D     (UI)                  2
```

Tried with this function but not working as expected.

```
drop_duplicates
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the strings around delimiter `,`, then dedupe using `dict.fromkeys` which also preserves the order of strings, finally `join` around delimiter `,`

```
df['Symbol'] = df['Symbol'].str.split(',').map(dict.fromkeys).str.join(',')
```

---

```
  Name          Symbol  Dummy
0    A  (BO),(AD),(TR)      2
1    B            (TV)      2
2    C            (HY)      2
3    D            (UI)      2
```

Comment: I have not seen `dict.fromkeys` used to remove dupes while retaining order yet – that's really neat! Definitely a nice exploit of insertion-ordered `dict`s.

Answer (score 0):

Another method

*#original DF*

| index | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | (BO),(BO),(AD),(TR) | 2 |

```
df.col1 = df.col1.str.split(',').apply(lambda x: sorted(set(x), key=x.index)).str.join(',')
df
```

*#output*

| index | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | (BO),(AD),(TR) | 2 |

**If values order not important you can simply do:**

```
df.col1 = df.col1.str.split(',').apply(lambda x: set(x)).str.join(',')
df
```

*#output*

| index | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | (AD),(BO),(TR) | 2 |